# What is ivar in Rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, controller

I can see `ivar` term mentioned many times here https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/18950#issuecomment-77924771 but can't find straight forward explanation what is the iVar.

What is it and can this term be used outside controller context?

Comment: ivar stands for instance variable. An instance variable belongs to an object of a given class and in rails is mainly used in controllers and views. This is from the github issue you have posted: 'iVars essentially serve as the recommended "API" between controllers and views.'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ivar stands for instance variable. An instance variable is bound to an object of a given class and, in rails, is mainly used in controllers and views.

This is from the github issue you have posted: 'iVars essentially serve as the recommended "API" between controllers and views.'

For example in your controller:

```
def new
  @post_ivar = Post.new
end
```

You can now use this 'ivar' in your view for your new action, i.e. new.haml:

```
= form_for @post_ivar do |f|
  = f.text_field :headline
  -# ...
```